# Why doesn't Python request show up in Python http server printout?

Tags: python, server, python-requests

I am running a simple python server from home. The script is called server.py

```
#server.py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
import socketserver


class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print('GET!',self.headers)
    def do_POST(self):
        print('POST!',self.headers)


#this is for ending requests which last too long...like from webcrawling bots n such...
class ForkingHTTPServer(socketserver.ForkingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    def finish_request(self, request, client_address):
        request.settimeout(60)  
        HTTPServer.finish_request(self, request, client_address)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#==============================================================================
###############################################################################
def main():
    try:
        print('Server started!')
        srvr = ForkingHTTPServer(('', 8080),MyHandler)
        srvr.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('^C received, shutting down server')
        srvr.socket.close()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#==============================================================================
###############################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this server from Terminal, it prints out the headers of GET and POST requests made to it.

When I connect to this server via a browser on my laptop like Chrome or Firefox etc., I can see in the server computer's Terminal that I have requested stuff from that browser (it prints out the headers). No problems, all as expected.

HOWEVER...I intend to use this server in conjunction with a standalone python app, and so I'd like to use the python requests module to communicate with this server.

The problem is...when I use python requests...pretty much nothing happens? As in, nothing is printed in the Terminal. I dunno what is up?
Here is the python requests script I'm using...

```
#test_request.py
import requests

print('testing requests...')

s=requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'some_kinda_special_data':'and_here_it_IS'})

r = s.post('http://www.<myspecialreservedwebsiteforthis>.com/')

r_data = vars(r)
for thing in r_data:
    print(thing, r_data[thing])
```

I'm planning on using POST requests from this to-be-designed app to be able to retrieve data from the server I'm running based on stuff I include in the headers (and also running py scripts on the server first before sending a response). I figure it'd be easier to homebrew my own security this way (different topic, but the idea is that server will reject any incoming requests that don't have a special code in the headers somewhere). But when I run this test_request.py script, there is NOTHING PRINTED in the server terminal like there is when I connect via a browser...it's not even showing up.
WHY?

Also, after around 2 minutes of waiting (which is also something I need to figure out how to fix...), I get back SOME STUFF in the test_request Terminal when I run test_request.py including this: '

You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms'
Still, even if the test_request.py Terminal eventually prints SOMETHING out, the server Terminal still prints nothing...

ALSO: the server is being run on a separate computer than the one making python requests to it (or browser requests to it).

Insight as to why python requests isn't "showing up" in the server Terminal, as well as why python requests hangs for 2+ minutes EVERY TIME it tries to get stuff from this server, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you remember to include the port number (8080) in your `http://www.<myspecialreservedwebsiteforthis>.com/` requests. In other words, did you try: `http://www.<myspecialreservedwebsiteforthis>.com:8080/`?

Comment: There also might be a firewall/NAT between the two servers, you need to make sure to set-up port forwarding correctly in your infrastructure

Comment: ...I totally did not include the port number in my request! Having added ```:8080``` to my requests, it works as expected! Much appreciated Omer!